# Cannot push/pull GitLab when ssh from other machine

Tags: gitlab

I have a machine setup for development, I can push/pull from GitLab locally. When I connect to that machine via SSH (terminal or vs code), all the actions failed with "Permission denied (publickey)."
what was the problem and how do I fix it?
thanks.

I have checked the SSH Keys under User Settings, keys from both machines (the development machine and the one SSH from) are valid.

as suggest by **@Martheen**

> the output of ssh git@gitlab.com -T -vvv

| local | from ssh |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent | debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent |
| debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS | debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS |
| debug3: receive packet: type 21 | debug3: receive packet: type 21 |
| debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received | debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received |
| debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 | debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 |
| debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks | debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks |
| debug2: key: some_user@some_place.com (0x55........), agent |  |
| debug2: key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)) | debug2: key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)) |
| debug2: key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)) | debug2: key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)) |
| debug2: key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)) | debug2: key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)) |
| debug2: key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)) | debug2: key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)) |
| ... | ... |
| debug1: Offering public key: ED25519 SHA256:G+...... | debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa |
| debug3: send_pubkey_test | no such identity: ... |
| ... | ... |

then the local finished to test and the ssh one failed.

Comment: When you're connected through SSH, what is the output of `ssh git@gitlab.com -T`? If it doesn't welcome you with your username, check the output of  `ssh git@gitlab.com -T -vvv` and compare it to what happen when you run it locally.

Comment: You removed the interesting bits! What does '/home/xxx/' evaluate to in each case? The same? ssh is looking for keys in the user's home folder, if '/home/xxx/' differs, the keys differ.

Comment: in ~/.ssh are openssh private and public keys some_name and some_name.pub, dont have any keys with default names (id_rsa, id_dsa, id_ecdsa, id_ed25519), thus the (nil) in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in `~/.ssh` are openssh private and public keys some_name and some_name.pub, dont have any keys with default names (id_rsa, id_dsa, id_ecdsa, id_ed25519), thus the (nil) in the log.

That means, if any push/SSH connection is successful (with non-standard named keys), you should have a `~/.ssh/config` file.

Check its content for something like:

```
Host gh
  Hostname gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/some_name
```

If you do have such an entry, check the output of `ssh -Tv gh`: it should authenticate you with the right user.

Use the Git remote URL `gh:me/myrepo`.

---

> How the git with ssh use the key and why it work locally without the config files?

- The Git with SSH will use the right key if the `git remote origin` used for that repository is `gh:me/myrepo` (not `git@gitlab.com:my/myrepo`)
- it is working locally if your keys have the standard name, or if you also have a `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: This works! thank you. Can someone please point me out how the git with ssh use the key and why it work locally without the config files?